# Jestjs - database connection created in beforeEach block becomes undefined in test block

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, typeorm

I have setup my project so that once a database connection is made an event is emitted. The app starts after this.

When unit testing I setup a local variable, create the database connection inside `beforeEach` and save the connection to the local variable.

Within this `beforeEach` block I can see that the database is connected. However, if I check inside a `test` block the local variable returns `undefined`. What is the correct approach for this?

```
- db.config.ts -
export async function connectToDatabase(mediator: EventEmitter) {
  const connectionOptions = await getConnectionOptions();

  const dbConnection = await createConnection(connectionOptions);

  mediator.emit('db.ready', dbConnection);
}

- index.ts -
const mediator = new EventEmitter();

connectToDatabase(mediator);

mediator.on('db.ready', (db: Connection) => {
  app.listen(3000);
  console.log('app started');
});
```

Test

```
describe('Jest Tests', () => {
    const mediator = new EventEmitter();
    let dbConnection: Connection;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        connectToDatabase(mediator);

        mediator.on('db.ready', (db: Connection) => {
           dbConnection = db;
           console.log(dbConnection.isConnected); // **returns TRUE**
        }
    }

    test('Testing db connection', () => {
        console.log(dbConnection.isConnected); // **dbConnection undefined**
    }
}
```

I also tried placing the local variables outside the `describe` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`beforeEach` hook callback returns immediately, although it is `async`. You need to explicitly return a Promise from it, and fulfill it only when the `db.ready` event is emitted (or reject it on a certain timeout).

In pseudo code, it should look like this:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    return new Promise(async (fulfill, reject) => {
        await connectToDatabase(mediator);
        mediator.on('db.ready', db => {
            dbConnection = db;
            fulfill();
        })
        // reject on timeout
    })
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, even with this I still get the same error. Do I need to change something inside the `test` block ?

Comment: Never mind, it works! I made the mistake of adding `fulfill()` outside the `mediator.on` method instead of inside. Also, I learned that `beforeEach(async () => {
    return new Promise(async (fulfill, reject) => {` can be simplified to `beforeEach(async (fulfill) => {` (See my answer below)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a bit more clarity to my comment, the following piece of code worked;

```
beforeEach(async (done) => {
  connectToDatabase(mediator);
  mediator.on('db.ready', (db: Connection) => {
      dbConnection = db;
      done();
  });
});
```